# Delphi - Destroy component

Tags: delphi, components, destroy

I have a problem with the following example.I have a button that creates a runtime Panel with more components:

```
Panel := TPanel.Create(self);
Panel.Parent := FlowPanel;
Panel.Align := alTop;
Panel.Height := 24;
Panel.Width := FlowPanel.Width;

Text := TLabel.Create(self);
Text.Parent := Panel;
Text.Align := alLeft;
Text.Caption := Query.FieldByName('Nazev').AsString;
Text.AlignWithMargins := True;
Text.Tag := Data_Id;
Text.Width := 100;

Button := TButton.Create(self);
Button.Parent := Panel;
Button.Caption := 'Odstranit';
Button.Align := alRight;
Button.Margins.Top := 0;
Button.Margins.Bottom := 0;
Button.AlignWithMargins := True;
Button.OnClick := DeleteFlowPanelItem;
```

Button has OnClick event on DeleteFlowPanelItem;

```
procedure TAdminTypyPlochy.DeleteFlowPanelItem(Sender: TObject);
var
  myPanel: TPanel;
begin
  myPanel := TPanel(TButton(Sender).Parent);
  myPanel.Free;
end;
```

And when you click on that, although I component is deleted but also when it pops up message Access violation at address ... Why ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The function that calls your button `OnClick` event handler is a method of that same button. Your `OnClick` event deleted the button and so when the event handler returns, you are now executing in an instance method of an object that has been destroyed.

You need to postpone the destruction of the button until the button click event handling is complete. Use `PostMessage` to post a custom message that identifies which button to destroy. Handle that message by destroying the specified button. For instance the button could be passed in `lParam`.

Personally I'd use `AllocateHWnd` to create a window that can be the target for these messages. That way you can be certain to avoid problems with window re-creation.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are freeing the button from within the button's `OnClick` event handler. This is simply not allowed. The button is owned by this panel, therefore, when you free the panel, it also free's this button - before its event handler finishes executing.

Comment: Thanks for the information.You can do this in other ways?

Comment: Actually I just realized the button is *not* owned by the panel, but by something else. I don't know in what context `self` is in your code. Besides that, one solution could be using Windows Messages.

Comment: here is complete source of unit: [link](http://pastebin.com/vYvNFigA)